# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [755, 8]

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, confusion-matrix

i have made the model but while creating the confusion matrix i'm getting some error.

the code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
data,Label = shuffle(A,label,random_state=2)
train_data = [data,Label]
                                                #loading the dataset
X,Y = [train_data[0],train_data[1]]
                                                 #splitting into train and test set
 X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test= train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.4,random_state 
    =4)
                                                    #splitting test into test and validation set

 x_test,x_validation,y_test,y_validation=train_test_split(X_test,Y_test,test_size=0.5,random_state=4)

print (X_train.shape)
```

the output is:

```
(2266, 196608)



X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0],256,256,3))

x_validation = x_validation.reshape((x_validation.shape[0],256,256,3))

x_test =x_test.reshape((x_test.shape[0],256,256,3))

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')

x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32')

x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

X_train=X_train/255

x_test = x_test / 255

x_validation = x_validation/255

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train,8)

y_validation = np_utils.to_categorical(y_validation,8)

y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test,8)

print(y_test.shape)
(755, 8)
```

then i created the model and found the test accuracy.
Now while creating confusion matrix i'm getting some error

```
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,folder))
```

The error is as follows:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-6d9d65ab1411> in <module>
----> 1 print(confusion_matrix(y_test,folder))

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py in confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels, sample_weight)
    251 
    252     """
--> 253     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    254     if y_type not in ("binary", "multiclass"):
    255         raise ValueError("%s is not supported" % y_type)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     69     y_pred : array or indicator matrix
     70     """
---> 71     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     72     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
     73     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    203     if len(uniques) > 1:
    204         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 205                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    206 
    207 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [755, 8]
```

please help me with this

Comment: I would suggest that you add some sample data to your post so that somebody can just copy, paste and debug it on their own computer (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) )

Answer (score 0):

```
steps=(len(test_generator))
```

Solved my problem.